# Second application layout for bilingual Rails site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a web site in Spanish, which I need to make an exact copy of into English. However, the navbar labels come from the application controller, which is used for every page on the site.

Is it possible to make an application layout which will only be applied to the Spanish pages, and a second application layout for the English pages? I also need a link to ENG and SPA to change between each version.

To sum up:

1. Can I make a second application layout?
2. How do I link the new application layout to the views?

Answer (score 1):

You can define a method on your controller that will set the correct layout based on selected language or other parameters.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  layout :choose_layout

  protected

  def choose_layout
    # replace this condition with your own
    if spanish_layout?
      "application_es"
    else
      "application_en"
    end
  end
end
```

This will expect that you have two files `app/views/layouts/application_es.*` and `app/views/layouts/application_en.*`. Of course you can define this method not on `ApplicationController` but some other child controller. Up to you.

Comment: great. could you explain a bit more about your code. 1. what does "layout :choose_layout" do?  2. what is "protected" and why is it necessary? 3. what does "spanish_layout" refer to and where is it defined?

Comment: i understand "layout :choose_layout" now. its just 2 and 3 i am not sure of now in your code.

Comment: one other thing: is it possible to use a partial. since really the only part i need to be different is the navbar. one english and one Spanish. everything else in the layout is identical. obviously the navbar will link to different view according to whether it is english or spanish